# Как передать в хранимую процедуру на C?

Tags: timestamp

Поле string '2017-07-02 18:00:00.000000', после

```
new TimeStamp(...);
```

Остаётся дата без 5 последних знаков

Comment: Вообще ничего не понятно... Каких 5 знаков... После чего...

Comment: Ищите перезагрузку где есть милисекунды. Укажите язык и библиотеку где вы выхватили данный класс.